# Max date should appear automatically in Tableau after extract refresh

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a report in Tableau and wanted to show the latest date in dashboard whenever I refresh the data. My data also contains last one month's data points. And on daily basis, we are refreshing the data.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where do you want to show Max date? this will decide the exact process

Comment: Hi Siva, I am showing the date in dashboard where user can change the date manually and see that particular date's reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the latest date in your dashboard you can just have a sheet with max(date_field) and drag that sheet onto your dashboard.
If you want that date to change dynamically with the users choice of periods that you just need to look at "Apply to worksheets" on your dashboard filter.